# Using ASP and INSERT INTO -

Tags: sql, asp-classic, vbscript, ado

I am trying to create a simple page that enters data in to a database and my code is below.

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" %>
<% Option Explicit %>
<!--#include FILE=dbcano.inc-->
<%

dim username,password,f_name,l_name,objConn,objs,query

username   = Request.Form("user")
password   = Request.Form("pass")
f_name     = Request.Form("fname")
l_name     = Request.Form("lname")

if((f_name <> null) or (f_name <> "")) then
    response.redirect("patti_account.asp")
else
    Set objConn = ConnectDB()
    query       = "INSERT INTO user (username,password,f_name,l_name) VALUES ('"& username &"','"& password &"','"& f_name &"','"& l_name &"')"
    Set objs    = objConn.Execute(query)

    Response.Redirect ("thankyou.asp")

end if

%>
```

I am getting this error when I run my page:

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL
>   Server error '80040e14'
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'user'.
>
> create_account.asp, line 18

I have checked everything, my field names exist and my table name is correct as well.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You code is littered with SQL injection, think what happens when I enter my name as:

'; DROP TABLE user;

Comment: TravisO - If i validate my code even on both client side and server side?

Comment: ... the kind of code that gives DBA's nightmares.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**User** is a reserved word in SQL server. Put it into square brackets, e.g. **[user]**.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you Martin. I didnt even think of checking to see if "user" was a reserved word

Answer (score 1):

This is vulnerable to SQL Injection.  Imagine what would happen if someone put this in for the last name:

```
');DROP Table [user];--
```

Fix it or I will personally track you down and beat you with a wet noodle until you do.

Comment: +1 for the wet noodle beating; Good point about injection too :)

Comment: Thank you Joel! I will make sure to keep an eye on this..thanks again.

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to:

```
query       = "INSERT INTO [user] (username,password,f_name,l_name) VALUES ('"& username &"','"& password &"','"& f_name &"','"& l_name &"')"
```

(escape the table name since it is a reserved word)

Also, don't forget to validate keyboard input since this code is subject to SQL injection attacks.